# Offset target panel from fixed top navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an anchor tag `<a href="#target">jump</a>` that redirects to the `target` panel. This panel, after being redirected, is hidden behind my fixed top navbar. I have tried 2 different ways in CSS to offset the panel but they don't work correctly.

Is there a way to offset the panel from the navbar, but still keep its border in the correct position? Preferably using only CSS and HTML.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#mytarget {
  border-color: red
}

/* This doesn't work */
/*#mytarget:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -50px; 
  height: 50px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}*/


/* This works but border overlaps */
#mytarget:target {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">Fixed Top Navbar</div>
  </nav>

  <div>Click on panel headers to open all panels, then <a href="#mytarget">jump to target</a></div>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel1">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Header 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" id="mytarget">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#targetpanel">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Target Panel Header</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="targetpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Target Panel Body Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel3">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Header 3</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to prevent the anchor padding/margin from affecting your panel styling is to separate them. You can either:

1. move the id to the `<h3>` element instead of the panel element, as it is set to have no padding, margin or border so it won't affect its display, or
2. create separate anchor elements that you can style separately.

If you were to create separate anchor elements, add the anchor as the first element in the panel:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <a id="mytarget"></a>
   <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#targetpanel">
       [...]
```

And make your anchor's CSS be:

```
#mytarget:target {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  display:block;
}
```

**Working Example**:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#mytarget {
  border-color: red
}

#mytarget:target {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">Fixed Top Navbar</div>
  </nav>

  <div>Click on panel headers to open all panels, then <a href="#mytarget">jump to target</a></div>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel1">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Header 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
       <a id="mytarget"></a>
       <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#targetpanel">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Target Panel Header</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="targetpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Target Panel Body Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel3">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Header 3</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```